# Hi guys, I'm working on Writing your first Django app, part 2 tutorial, and I tried _str_() function and it doesn't give me the same result

Tags: django

this is my Question class in models.py :

```
class Question(models.Model):
     question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
     def _str_(self):
         return self.question_text
```

when I execute : Question.objects.all()
it gives me : <QuerySet [<Question: Question object (1)>, <Question: Question object (2)>]>
any ideas ???

Comment: It is `__str__` with double underscores.

Comment: its double score each, i did trick me too once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
class Question(models.Model):
     question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
     def __str__(self):
         return self.question_text
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use double underscore(__) not single(_) for your [dunder](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text
```

Comment: Please accept the question if it worked for you.